# What is the corresponding function for DeviceIoControl (C++) in C#.net?

Tags: c#, c++

DeviceIoControl is used in C++ to communicate with USB device connected to the System. I want to use the same functionality in C#.net, but I can't able find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can PInvoke it:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeviceIoControl.html